# If I have a stepper where the 1st step is done, can I give the user the chance to edit this steps in the next ones?

Tags: component

I'm working on a stepper with 3 steps, where the first one is adding your address. Once the user move forward to the next step, can I give them the chance to edit that address but without make them go back to the first step? Like for example opening a sidebar and let them edit the address there?

Is it a bad practice if I make the user go back to step 1 when is already at the second or at the third one?

we don't have a Previous button on our design, so I believe it's not okay to make them go back, it's unexpectable. But I'd like to hear your opinions

Answer (score 0):

This problem falls under Nielsen's usability heuristic #3. It states:

> Users often make mistakes or change their minds. Allow them to exit a flow or undo their last action and go back to the system’s previous state.

[Source](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/user-control-and-freedom/)

I would highly suggest allowing user to be able to go back to previous step as it would provide user with a control of the flow.